# What kind of dash is used in the combination of artist and song title?

Tags: typography

Which one is correct?

- *Def Leppard ‒ Photograph* (figure dash, `U+2012`),
- *Def Leppard – Photograph* (n-dash, `U+2013`),
- *Def Leppard — Photograph* (m-dash, `U+2014`) or
- *Def Leppard ― Photograph* (horizontal bar, `U+2015`).

Comment: Is this question on which char is typographical correct *and* how you can reproduce it in TeX (or related systems)? If not, I would consider to migrate it to another SX site.

Comment: So long as you don't use a hyphen and you're consistent, it's just a stylistic choice. There's no ‘correct’ choice.

Comment: @Ruben If there is better site to ask about typography you may well migrate it there.

Comment: @mcb the matter is just about your question beeing related to TeX, not if some site is better. Pragmatically speaking, TeX of course has to do with typography and drawing a line is impossible. But, as far as your question does not have any contact to some TeX code - at the moment - I would consider (sorry for reperating myself) to migrate it *or* to edit it. An appropriate choice could be the graphic design site. They have a 'typography' tag too.

Comment: I would also consider the context of where this appears. In an pop-up by my media player? N- or m-dash. In a list of favorite songs? I’d use a colon. In running text? I’d probably use none of your choices but text, i.e. "song 'Photograph' by artist Def Leppard".